# Push notification custom sound not played instead of default sound

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform, push-notification

My problem is here:

I use Parse Push Notifications services, all works fine, I receive local notifications on the device, all works, but now the problem is at that point: the custom sound isn't played, instead, this is the default iOS notification sound that is played.

All is done in the rules, I have a supported packaged sound in ".wav" verified with QuickTime player that confirmed the custom sound file is in "PCM linear" format.

The sound file, is correctly present in  the main bundle of the application and copied if needed in copy bundle resources (furthermore, the code in AppDelegate is looking correct)

I show you the code for more details:

```
NSDictionary *data = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
    @"You have received an coin !", @"alert",
    @"Increment", @"badge",
    @"custom_bell.wav", @"sound",
    nil];
PFPush *push = [[PFPush alloc] init];
[push setData:data];
[push sendPushInBackground];
```

What am I missing with setting up ? Why am I wrong ? Is something changed in iOS 8 ?

Comment: Can you please add complete path of the wav file like project path/custom_bell.wav.

Comment: Users/MWill/Coinproject/custom_bell.wav as given in QuickTime Player

Answer (score 2):

According to the push notification guide:

"You can package the audio data in an aiff, wav, or caf file. Then, in Xcode, add the sound file to your project as a nonlocalized resource of the application bundle."

It doesn't say anything about MP3s. I've used aif files which worked. I'd stick to what Apple specifies. Check here for more info: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/IPhoneOSClientImp/IPhoneOSClientImp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH103-SW6

Comment: I read some other almost similar posts, that does not solved my problem, and I thought that was a Parse issue, I tried all of the according answers, without results... I changed the "sound" file in payload in aiff and after in wav package ... Without results too :(

Comment: I saw a post talking about info property list "info.plist" that I had to specify the notification sound in the "info.plist" but without any other indication...

Comment: LKM, could you give more info about how did you added your sounds to the info.plist file? thanks

Answer (score 0):

yes  something changed in iOS 8 because in IOS 8 if the audio play time is more than 30 second the audio is not play, if less than 30 sec then you play it easily

Comment: My custom song is less that 30 seconds, it takes less than 1 sec that's why I don't understand :/

Comment: If I add it to "mp3" instead of "wav" or "aiff" it plays anything, but if I add "wav or "aiff" the default sound is still played instead

Comment: Where do you place your sounds? I'm not able to play any of them. Tried all codecs. Dont know what else do.